# How to create a line that spans automatically right from the text til the end of the text frame

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, automation, indesign-scripting

I am looking for a solution how to create a line that automatically spans to the right from the conditional text:
[image: Language 1]

As you can see above I just solved it at first with a static line. As soon as we change the language this doesn't work as the text is longer and crosses the line:
[image: Langiage 2]

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no completely straightforward way to do this. Some tricks are needed. I have two different suggestions. Each with their own pros and cons.

## Use Paragraph Rules

This is an approach where you use a *Paragraph Rule Above* to create the wanted line and a *Paragraph Rule Below* to hide the part of the rule that's under the text.

**Pro:** This can be done entirely in the heading's *Paragraph Style*.

**Con:** The heading must always be on the same background color or the rule below will be visible.

### Method

Enter the heading's *Paragraph Style Options*.

Under *Paragraph Rules* add a *Rule Above* which is styled like you want it. For example like this:

[image]

This creates a rule that spans the entire column:

[image]

Now add a *Rule Below*. We need to set it up so it covers the part of the rule we don't want to see. But for it to display nicely on screen we have to make sure there is an overlap.

Set *Weight* to for example 2 points more than the rule above.

Set *Color* to the color of the background.

Set *Width* to *Text*.

Set a small negative *Left Indent*, for example -1 pt.

Set *Right Indent* to whatever space you want between the text and the rule.

Set *Offset* to half of the sum of the weights of the two rules. If you have an offset on the rule above, this needs to be subtracted.

In my example I use these settings:

[image]

This creates the wanted look:

[image]

While setting up the rule below, it might be a good idea to set the color to something visible and zoom in on a header. This is how it looks if I choose cyan for the rule below:

[image]

## Use a Right Indent Tab with underline

This is a little simpler approach where you insert a *Right Indent Tab* at the end of each heading and style it with an underline.

**Pro:** The heading can be on any background.

**Con:** You have to add characters to the text.

### Method

Insert a space and a *Right Indent Tab* (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>) at the end of each heading:

[image]

Select the *Right Indent Tab* and copy it to clipboard for later use.

Create a new *Character Style* and use *Underline Options* to style the line like you want it. For example like this:

[image]

Enter the heading's *Paragraph Style Options*.

Under *GREP Style*, add a new *GREP Style*.

Set *Apply Style* to the *Character Style* you just created.

In the *To Text* field, paste in the *Right Indent Tab* you copied earlier.

It should look something like this:

[image]

Now any *Right Indent Tab* in a heading automatically gets an underline.

The result looks similar to the other approach:

[image]

Only difference is that the space between the text and the line is given by the white space character you choose to insert.

Comment: Great, thank you!